# Wordpress Rewrite Url with arugments

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I did not find any useful tips from google search and I wrote the same question in wordpress forum but there is no reply

I am writing the complete step here

First step I am redirect page  to custom post archive page

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'plu_redirects' );
//I am saving in the session the post_id which is the event
$_SESSION['event_page'] = $_GET[ 'event' ];

wp_safe_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link('plug') );

In the archive page I am trying to get the post by id or if session not exists then get the latest post.

```
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['event_page'])) :
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'plug',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'schedule'
                )
            )
        );
        query_posts($args);
    else :
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'plug',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                'p' => $_SESSION['event_page'],
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'schedule'
                )
            )
        );
        query_posts($args);         endif;
```

But this is always getting the last record when session is set ...Why?
I need to is there a better way it code can be written instead of using the session and also I don't require the loop as I am getting only  one record.
I am having the problem in the archive page and the code which I have added is working . but not professional..

Comment: You'll probably get a lot more help if you show what research you have done so far, what you have tried, what that got you instead of what you were aiming for.  Right now your question is pretty vauge and looks similar to "Please do all my work for me for free."

Comment: I did not know about the query_vars.. may be it works  instead of using the session.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using $_SESSION variables we'll register a query variable.

```
function wpa_91718_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'event_page';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa_91718_query_var' );
```

Then we can modify the query before it is run using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

If I understood you and your code correctly, then if the query var is present in the URL, you want to search for the post with that ID.  Otherwise, you just want to show the most recent CPT with the 'schedule' term in the 'event_type' taxonomy.

I think this can be done via:

```
function wpa_91718_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // only modify the main query and only on the front-end
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'plug' ) ) {
      // Display only 1 post for the cpt archive
      set_query_var( 'posts_per_page', 1 );

      // if query var exists search for that particular post ID number
      if ( $event_page = get_query_var( 'event_page' ) ){
        set_query_var( 'p', (int) $event_page );
      // otherwise get the most recent post of event_type taxonomy
      } else {
        set_query_var( 'event_type', 'schedule' );
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','wpa_91718_pre_get_posts' );
```

Totally untested, but I think it should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks..But this was really old question..No body has replied..Yesterday somebody stunned me by voting down...So I commented to my questions. It can be done using a query vars..but as  I was new to worpdress I did not know about query vars before..

Comment: That downvote must've been why it was on the front page when I answered it. If the question is from this year, it must not even that old yet. If you get a chance to test this out, let me know if it works.